# Account registration - verify business relationship

Tags: validation, experience-cloud, self-registration, user-registration, verification

My customer wants their Experience Cloud users to have ability to self register, however, we need to connect them to the correct account or create account if account is validated.

My original idea was to verify user registration business email and validate if email domain coincides with any existing account domain, and if that is the case, then register the user and connect it to the existing account.

If email domain doesn't match any existing account domain, we need some validation or verification that the user belongs to the claimed company and that such company truly exists, and this is not DDoS or a spam bot registering fake companies or companies they don't belong to.

I understand that we could simply create generic `Unknown account` and just allow the user to register anyway and connect the user to such generic unknown account, but I wonder if there is any better way to tackle this? Because I definitely don't want to suggest to client a generic unknown account solution which may lead to both  [Data Skews](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_parent_child_data_skew.htm) and [Ownership Skews](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership_data_skew.htm).

Should we request the user who wants to register to provide DUNS number or some other unique identifier for a company for which we haven't found an account record? Would that be sufficient to avoid fake registrations?

Would D&B Optimizer for Salesforce (the data.com replacement) be helpful for this?

Comment: This is a very customer-specific question, these vary from customer to customer. Email verification is a good idea but far from foolproof. Providing a DUNS number is meaningless, that's public info. Ask your customer how much risk they're willing to live with if someone not associated with, say, "General Motors" in real life gets linked to that account in SF.